# How to implement a comparator logic gate in Quartus software?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra, quartus

Been trying for hours...How do I properly implement the following expressions:

F0 = A0'A1'B0 + A0'B0B1 + A0B0'B1' + A1'B0B1
F1 = A1'B1 + A0'A1B1' + A0A1'B0' + A0B0'B1 + A1B0B1'

I'm using NAND & NOT gates[image]

Comment: What exactly your problem is?

Comment: Call me an amateur but how do I fix this. I'm desperate. Is there a better way to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is (as far as I can tell, the not gates are not going in the right direction) I circled this red

The second problem is you are using NAND gates not AND gates (green circle)

[image]